# display ko.observable with html binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, observable

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XuMzS/4/

html:

```
<input data-bind="value: Total" type="text" />
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" data-bind="value: testHtml, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
</textarea>
<p>Html:</p>
<div class="wrapper">
<div data-bind="html: testHtml"></div>
<br />
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function viewModel() {
var self = this;
self.Total = ko.observable("1337");
self.testHtml = ko.observable();

}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

What I am trying to do is to display the observable **Total** by writing the code that is needed ***inside the textarea*** (which displays html in the div below it).
Like if I wrote:

```
<span data-bind="text: Total"></span>
```

But nothing is displayed if I write that code in. Otherwise normal html is working.
Is there some way you can do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking http://jsfiddle.net/XuMzS/2/

Comment: I want to do what you just did by writing that code in the textarea :)

Comment: I guess you need a callback when updating to re-apply bindings.

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html doing basically the same as the base one

Comment: not getting it, but I'll read more

Comment: you need co create custom binding on your textarea and apply some binding to html which you create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a sample, I think this is what you are looking for.

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Total = ko.observable("1337");
    self.testHtml = ko.observable("<b>test</b><span data-bind=\"text: Total\"></span>");
    self.testHtmlWrapper = ko.computed(function () {
        return '<div id="dynamicContent">' + self.testHtml() + '</div>';
    });

    self.rebind = function () {
        try {
            ko.applyBindings(self, document.getElementById("dynamicContent"));
        } catch (e) {

        }
    };
    self.testHtml.subscribe(self.rebind);

}

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.rebind();
```

[**See Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XuMzS/7/)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the testHtml observable?

This can easily be accomplished using the code below.

Viewmodel:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Total = ko.observable("1337");
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Html:

```
<input data-bind="value: Total" type="text" />
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" data-bind="valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
<b>test</b><span data-bind="text: Total"></span>
</textarea>
<p>Html:</p>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div><b>test</b><span data-bind="text: Total"></span></div>
    <br />
</div>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4xvS/1/)

Comment: Read my question and you will understand.

Comment: I did read your question. That is why I posted the answer. You question a bit vague and that's why I couldn't understand why you needed it.